# Where to hold collection of objects Java

Tags: java

I'm not entirely sure how to describe this so the title is most likely not too descriptive but here goes: I have a collection of 'layout' objects which are loaded from a config file on startup and are used to format a users message. I am storing these objects in a hashmap with their name as a key as this is how they will be retrieved most of the time, however, I am unsure where I should locate this map and the accompanying add and remove methods. Should I add it as static variables/methods in the layout class or create a new class to hold it?

Comment: You really need to provide more information about the program you are writing, since where the map is stored depends greatly on how your project is structured and what parts of the code need access to that map.

Comment: Sounds like it's a config param, so it should be accesible everywhere... But it depends.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a singleton object that contains your map and use it everywhere you want to - [examples](http://www.concretepage.com/design-pattern/example-singleton-design-pattern-java).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's better have a new class with all the data/methods inside it and maintain an static variable to this class if you want that can be shared for all the classes that you need. A Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an Inversion of Dependencies rather than a plain Singleton pattern.

Create a single layout object on startup - its responsibility would be to accept the data and produce user messages. Then pass the object to all of its users as a property  or a constructor parameter.

This allows for easy testing of the Layout and of its users - separately and independently.

Comment: Isn't that the same as singleton? As you mentioned "Create a single layout object on startup".

Comment: Yes and no. Usually, the singleton pattern is implemented with a static ::instance() call. I am suggesting that the reference to singleton is passed around and stored in multiple objects. This makes testing each object separately much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much I would say your best bet is to create a new class to hold these, making sure you completely hide the implementation/internal of that `LayoutLoader` class (hashmap backed, loading from files, etc) from client classes. This is not that much more work than using static variables directly in your layout class, and this will improve testability and extensibility. At some point you may want to add various method to load layouts (from file, in-memory, etc), so you may end up with various `LayoutLoader` implementations.

But for now, you may just hold somewhere a static reference to that object and refactor in the future as needed.